# Custom schema for crm as per user. Any idea how to do it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am creating one CRM with customize fields. Can anyone give me an idea how to store that in data base?

Example:
**I am using a retail Crm , there I am creating a custom model type like Customer, Inside shop I would like to add fields like name, address, mobile etc.**

**Then user can add records to that customer model.** [Remember this customer model can be any thing custom made by user not predefined mongoose schema]

Can any one help me how to solve this.
Using: Nodejs, express, mongoose,

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is your question about customizing Dynamics 365 CE, or perhaps about interfacing? Is your question even about programming? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes Its about programming. If you know strapi then you or any other cms there you can create your own model then you can add entries to it. Is there any way we can do it in nodejs express app with mongoose

Comment: I am making a crm for retail business , I want to allow user to create their own model then add entries to that model. Is there any solution for that if you know?

Comment: For an example , User can create customer model where they will give name, address, phone number field. Then they can add entries to that customer model

Comment: I guess your question is too broad for SO. Also it is not related to Microsoft Dynamics CRM, so I removed that tag.